# Formatting TimeField in Django template shows nothing

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filters

I have a model that includes a TimeField object. I also have a django template that lists the time field in JSON Format
e.g.

```
...
   "time":"{{ mymodel.mytime }}",
...
```

Without specifying any formatting/filters etc, this results in the following e.g.

```
....
    "time":"5 p.m.",
....
```

However when I apply a time filter to my template i.e.

```
...
   "time":"{{ mymodel.mytime|time:"H:i" }}",
...
```

I get the following result:

```
...
    "time":"",
...
```

i.e. my time value is wiped out.  I am not sure what's going on? I also have a datefield in the same model and the filter I am applying to that (in the same django template) which works as defined.

I am using Django 1.4.2

What am I missing or not doing correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `time` is actually a time object, rather than a string? It seems odd that its default representation is "5 p.m." rather than "17:00:00" which I would expect.

Comment: In my model I have the following:     mytime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True).. So I would expect it to return a Time object right by default?

Answer (score 5):

You have put time format in double quotes too.
try:

```
"time":"{{ mymodel.mytime|time:'H:i' }}",
```

or

```
"time":'{{ mymodel.mytime|time:"H:i" }}',
```

or

```
"time":"{{ mymodel.mytime|time:\"H:i\" }}",
```

Answer (score 1):

time

Formats a time according to the given format.

Given format can be the predefined one TIME_FORMAT, or a custom format, same as the date filter. Note that the predefined format is locale-dependent.

For example:

{{ value|time:"H:i" }}

Answer (score 0):

For some bizzare reason, not sure what.. It has started working! Must have been a typo or something in the filter format?! Really weird.